# GreaseMonkey - sharing data between two scripts running in same tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

Is there a way to share data between two different greasemonkey scripts running in the same tab? I tried just setting a property of `document`, but it didn't work.

For example purposes, both scripts are like this:

```
if (document.shared === undefined) {
    document.shared = 0;
}
document.shared++;
```

When this is run, no matter what order the scripts execute in, each of them initialize the variable and increment it to 1 (according to logging in the actual scripts), rather than only one of them initializing and then sharing the variable.

It seems that, for user defined properties, each GM script gets it's own copy of `document`, which is not at all what I want.

P.S. Obviously two GreaseMonkey scripts which call something like `document.getElementById()` will be accessing the same page, but not for user defined properties apparently.

Comment: For something *simple* like this, just use `unsafeWindow.shared`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both scripts actually run in a sandbox and are made to not be able to access each other and their properties. I think the best way to communicate between these two properties is to create a communication element in the HTML containing some JSON or simply some data as a property and communicate that way. Then periodically check for an element with a predetermined ID, decode the JSON when found and send some data back.

Keep in mind that any instance of scopes and links between data will not remain. This means that you can not pass any functions this way to prevent you from still communicating between scripts anyway but simply passing some data (such as arrays, objects, numbers or strings) should be no problem as long as you can `JSON.stringify` them.

Comment: Would it be possible to add an event listener in both scripts, then dispatch whatever event that is with the data you need to send? That avoids having to manipulate the DOM to send messages. Maybe just `postMessage` a message back to the window, and have both scripts listen to `message`.

Comment: Looks like that is possible according to Oriol's answer. I have to say I haven't tested it myself but it sounds possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Web Messaging, e.g.

```
var me = /* some id */;
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  if(e.origin === location.origin && typeof e.data === 'object' && e.data.sender !== me) {
    console.log('received in script ' + me +': ', e.data.data);
  }
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  window.postMessage({sender: me, data: 'message from script ' + me}, location.origin);
});
```

If you use that script twice with `me = 1` and `me = 2`, you will see

```
received in script 2: message from script 1
received in script 1: message from script 2
```

Some notes:

- Run the scripts with `@run-at document-start` and wait until `DOMContentLoaded` before sending data. This way you will be sure the event listeners are already added.
- If you use `@grant none`, the page will be able to hijack the messaging by modifying `addEventListener` or `postMessage`.

  To avoid this, you can sandbox your scripts using e.g. `@grant GM_info`. That will also provide a way to generate an id for `me` (if you don't care about leaking this info to the page):

  ```
  me = GM_info.script.name + GM_info.script.namespace;
  ```
- The page will be able to read the messages sent by your scripts, and even send messages to your scripts as if it were any of your scripts.

  So don't send sensitive data nor trust the received data.